# laravel: using parameters from routes in blade forms

Tags: laravel

This is my add.blade.php.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => $id."/item", 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'id'=>'add')) }}
    {{ Form::text('title'}}
    {{Form::submit('Submit')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::resource('{categoryId}/item', 'ItemController');
```

This is my ItemController.php

```
public function create($categoryId){  
    return view('item.add', array('id' => $categoryId));
}
```

I am trying to add new item to a category. So I click add new and it opens `add.blade.php`. When I submit from add.blade.php, it is redirecting it to `item/create`. I think it is because of url in the form of `add.blade.php`. What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: try absolute URI `url($id . '/item')`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this:

```
{{Form::open(['route' => ['item.create', $id],'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'id'=>'add'])}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try prefix instead of append parameter

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{categoryId}'], function()
    Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
});
```

then use

```
route('item.create',['1']);
```

Here in your code just pass parameter and will work like this:

['route' => ['item.create', $id]

Answer (score 0):

your View

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => "/item/".$id , 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true', 'id'=>'add')) }}
    {{ Form::text('title'}}
    {{Form::submit('Submit')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

your Route

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
Route::post('/item/{categoryId}', 'ItemController@create');
```

your Controller

```
public function create($categoryId){ 
    $id = $categoryId;
    return view('item.add', compact('id'));
}
```